Installing RHEL 8 so that it is compliant with customized stigs
Need guidance regarding creating my own openscap profile based off of an existing profile that I can use too install Rhel in a standardized way that will already be compliant. I see that there is a way to use a kickstart with an addon entry referencing content-type= scap-security-guide and profile= xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig_gui.
%addon org_fedora_oscap
        content-type = scap-security-guide
        profile = xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig_gui
%end

What I need to know is how to I create my own version of that profile.
ALternatively, if I have a tailored file from previous scans can I convert that tailor profile into what I need?
Sincerely,
Yet Another Wannabe Linux Admin
